# Spark LDA - workers' local disks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lda

When I run LDA model with Scala script, it gets terminated with error "no space left" if number of iterations is large.

I check amount of space with following script:

```
val perNodeSpaceInGB = sc.parallelize(0 to 100).map { _ =>
val hostname = ("hostname".!!).trim
val spaceInGB = ("df /local_disk".!!).split(" +")(9).toInt / 1024 / 1024
//System.gc()
(hostname, spaceInGB)
}.collect.distinct
println(f"There are ${perNodeSpaceInGB.size} nodes in this cluster. Per node free space (in GB):\n--------------------------------------")
perNodeSpaceInGB.foreach{case (a, b) => println(f"$a\t\t$b%2.2f")}
val totalSpaceInGB = perNodeSpaceInGB.map(_._2).sum
```

And see that amount of free space is gradually decreasing until zero and termination. It seems like some temporary files are not deleted in time. Checkpoint is set to every 10 iterations.

Any hints?

Error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 885.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 885.0 (TID 586, 10.0.239.157): java.io.IOException: No space left on device
```

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same problem, did you guys figure out any solution?

Comment: No. But there is an alternative - use online training for LDA.

Comment: And the results were comprehensive as the DistributedLDAModel?

Comment: It's not that transparent how to compare quality of topics in this case between two methods. So, I don't know.